# Issue with calling a function inside a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I don't know if this is a simple question or not, but I couldn't find anything on it so I figured I would ask it.

I try to call a function in a while loop but it keeps on returning the same result until the condition is completed. The function `main()` is imported from another file and return a list with two elements `[a,b]`.

Those two elements are generated randomly, therefor they should change after every step. The function works perfectly fine if I call it on its own.

Here is my code so far, I hope someone can help me:

I thought there was something wrong with my list `x` so I tried to delete it after every step, but it doesn't change anything.

```
from some_module import main

def loop(variable):

    i = 0
    while i <= 5 :

        x = main(variable)
        a ,b = x[0], x[1]
        print a, b
        del x[:]
        i += 1
```

The code for main() is :

```
def main(file):
    iniciate(file)
    obtain_neighbours(initial_solution())
    get_all_costs(get_all_solutions())
    return get_best_solution()
```

And the random choice appears in the function initial_solution() :

```
#those list are being updated at every step
So = []
I_assign = []
I_available = ['1','2','3','4',...,'n']

def initial_solution():

    while len(I_available) != 0:
        update_I_assign()
        random_task = random.choice(I_assign)
        So.append(random_task)
        I_available.remove(random_task)
    return So

def get_best_solution():

    if min(i for i in all_cost) < calculate_cost(fill_station(So)):
         best_solution = solutions[all_cost.index(min(i for i in all_cost))]
         return [min(i for i in all_cost),best_solution]
    else:
        best_solution = fill_station(So)
        return [calculate_cost(fill_station(So)),best_solution]
```

It's pretty hard for me to show the rest of the code here because it's quite long. Hope the update helps you understand.

Comment: Show us the code for `main`.

Comment: Please update the main function in the question as well

Comment: Do you seed the rand with the same value each time?

Comment: My guess: `main` is seeding the random number generator with the current system time, so when it's called in very fast succession, the random number generator is seeded with the same time each iteration and yields the same numbers. But without seeing `main` that's just a guess.

Comment: You need to work a bit on your code before showing it here. Currently it's still hard to guess what's wrong, because the contents of `I_assign` are unknown. Please try to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What `update_I_assign()` do? copy the list from `I_available`?

Comment: I_assign copies some element of I_available under some conditions. Step by step I_available is being emptied and the list So being filled.